# Handling 404 error in Servlet

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I am trying to redirect to different error jsp base on status code

`statusCode = (Integer) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code")`

but it is throwing a null pointer error.
My web.xml is look like

```
<exception-type>404</exception-type><location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think entry in `web.xml` is not correct.It should be like below.The exception type should not be code,but a class.like below.

> The exception-type contains a fully qualified class
>           name of a Java exception type.

```
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
  </error-page>
```

If you want to handle `404`,than do like below.

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/AppExceptionHandler</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>Error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>